# Good practices with symfony 2 : Make a facebook like friend request

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, doctrine-orm, request

I am working on a Web App using Symfony2 and I'd like to make a facebook friend request like system.

User "A" ask permission to user "B" to do something. User "B" should see a notification asking confirmation.

I asked my self what is a good way to do that. I though about creating an entity "request" whit User "A" (Object), User "B" (user_id field, using ManyToOne relation in Doctrine), Type (string) and Date field.

However, using object type will serialize the User "A". It seems a little heavy. And Using User "A" id instead of all object is not really Object Programming friendly.

Answer (score 2):

You are definitely on the right track. This is how your are supposed to do it in Symfony2 with Doctrine2.

Create an entity `Request` containing the following fields:

- `id`
- `sender` (Many-to-One relationship to user entity)
- `receiver` (also Many-to-One relationship to user entity)
- `date`
- whatever more fields you use

Or, depending on your goal, you could directly add a row to a `Friendship` or `Action` entity and handle a field `confirmed` or `confirmed_time` which is false respectively NULL until the friendship/action has been confirmed or completed.